# Mass assignment error in nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, mass-assignment

`transaction.rb` model:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer, :tickets_attributes
  has_many :tickets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets
end
```

`ticket.rb` model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :booking_id, :quantity, :transaction_id
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :booking
end
```

in the view page i have a nested rails form for multiple entries of `ticket`:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :customer %>

  <% @sezzion.bookings.each do |booking| %>
      <%= booking.bookingdate %>:

      <%= f.fields_for :ticket do |t| %>
         <%= t.text_field :quantity, :value => 0, :class => "quantity" %>
         <%= t.hidden_field :booking_id, :value => booking.id %>
      <% end %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "create transaction" %>
<% end %>
```

When I'm submitting the form, I have the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in TransactionsController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ticket
```

I have `attr_accessible :tickets_attributes` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets` in the `transaction` model and there's still an error. Also when I add plural to the ticket on line `<%= f.fields_for :ticket do |t| %>`, the `quantity` field doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form `f` is based off of a `Transaction` object, which `has_many :tickets`.  I believe you should be using the plural `:tickets` rather than the singular `:ticket` in your `fields_for`.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :tickets do |t| %>
```

If you always want a new ticket, you may need to do:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :tickets, Ticket.new do |t| %>
```

to ensure that a create form shows up.

Comment: Thanks! Now with `<%= f.fields_for :tickets, Ticket.new do |t| %>` it is giving an error `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in TransactionsController#create Can't mass-assign protected attributes: quantity`. I already have `attr_accessible :tickets_attributes` in `transaction` model.

Answer (score 1):

total re-edit -- sorry its been a while I had to refresh my memory

**transaction.rb**  `tickets_attributes` is ok.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :customer, :tickets_attributes
    has_many :tickets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets
 end
```

**transaction_controller.rb**  you must build the tickets.

```
def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
    @transaction.tickets.build
end
```

**new.rb**  or in your form, `fields_for` must be for `:tickets` as rob as pointed out:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>

  ...

  <%= f.fields_for :tickets do |t| %>
     ...
```

I think you might be missing the `build` part in the controller. hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I did that part with plural `tickets`. With `:ticket_attributes` however, I'm having the error: `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in TransactionsController#create Can't mass-assign protected attributes: quantity, tickets_attributes`

Comment: I often find I forget to `build` the new nested attributes. Have you got done build in controller?